# How to display a new screen ontop of all other views in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I would like to display a new View/Scene (not sure which is best) on top of all views when a button is pressed. I currently have a project with multiple layers as shown below:

`ContentView.swift`

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        TabView(selection: $selection){
            PractiseMain()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "pencil")
                }
            TestMain()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "clock")
                }
...
```

`MyApp.swift`

```
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        RoutingView().environmentObject(sceneOnDisplay)
    }
...

struct RoutingView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var sceneOnDisplay: SceneOnDisplay
    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared
    
    var body: some View {
        switch sceneOnDisplay.scene {
        case 1:
            PractiseSceneView().transition(.scale)
        default:
            ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
        }
        
    }
}
```

Currently, I am showing new screens by replacing the root view in the `RoutingView`, when a button within the app changes `sceneOnDisplay.scene` we change the view. I'm not sure if this is a good idea in the long run. If I have 10 different screens then I do not want each view existing simultaneously.

I have tried using `NavigationView` but this only works for displaying children views and cannot display views outside of it's parent. The behaviour I'm trying to replicate is the same as launching a new `activity` in Android.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `ZStack`:

```
struct RoutingView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var sceneOnDisplay: SceneOnDisplay
    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            mainView
                .zIndex(1)
            if showOverlay { // this can be some environment variable (similar to `sceneOnDisplay`)
                Text("Overlay")
                    .zIndex(2)
            }
        }
    }

    var mainView: some View {
        switch sceneOnDisplay.scene {
        case 1:
            PractiseSceneView().transition(.scale)
        default:
            ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
        }
        
    }
}
```